# Difference between AWS EKS and ECS Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, amazon-eks

I used ECS Fargate and it provides containerization, auto-scaling based on request count, CPU and Memory.
It is working as expected.

I start to explore the AWS EKS feature and I didn't see any advantage in using this as all are provided by ECS Fargate.

Could someone help me understand where to use ECS Fargate and Where to use AWS EKS?

Anyhelp is appreciated.

Thanks,
Harry

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would use [`AWS EKS`](https://aws.amazon.com/eks/) if you want to use **Kubernetes**.
Since Kubernetes is a standard, you could in theory move your application from `AWS EKS` to other cloud providers like Azure, Google Cloud, or DigitalOcean easily since they all support Kubernetes.

If you don't care about Kubernetes then I find that [`AWS ECS`](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/) with the [`AWS Fargate`](https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/) [Serverless compute for containers] deployment type is currently the easiest method of running Docker containers on AWS.

Note that Amazon is [actively working on](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/projects/1?card_filter_query=fargate) adding the Fargate deployment type to the EKS service.
I would check back after [the AWS re:invent conference](https://reinvent.awsevents.com/) next month to see how things have changed in this area.

Comment: I would like to know what is the advantage of using 'Kubernetes' over 'ECS fargate'

Comment: @Harry the ability to move it to other cloud providers, because you aren't locked into Amazon's proprietary ECS implementation, is the advantage. I tried to make that clear in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

We hear these questions often and I tried to capture some of the core principles of these comparisons/positioning in [this blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/the-role-of-aws-fargate-in-the-container-world/).